# Terraform external data source EKS thumbprint not working sometimes

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, openid-connect, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I've tried to retrieve the existing EKS certificate thumbprint with Terraform's external datasource with the following code:

**thumbprint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

THUMBPRINT=$(echo | openssl s_client -servername oidc.eks.${1}.amazonaws.com -showcerts -connect oidc.eks.${1}.amazonaws.com:443 2>&- | tac | sed -n '/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/,/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/p; /-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/q' | tac | openssl x509 -fingerprint -noout | sed 's/://g' | awk -F= '{print tolower($2)}')
THUMBPRINT_JSON="{\"thumbprint\": \"${THUMBPRINT}\"}"
echo $THUMBPRINT_JSON
```

**data.tf**

```
data "external" "thumbprint" {
  program = ["${path.root}/scripts/thumbprint.sh", data.aws_region.current.name]
}
```

**openid.tf**

```
resource "aws_iam_openid_connect_provider" "openid" {
  depends_on      = [data.external.thumbprint]
  client_id_list  = ["sts.amazonaws.com"]
  thumbprint_list = [data.external.thumbprint.result.thumbprint]
  url             = data.aws_eks_cluster.this.identity.0.oidc.0.issuer
}
```

And to get the thumbprint from the above data source with `data.external.thumbprint.result.thumbprint`.

The main problem is I am confused that sometimes I got data from **thumbprint** and sometimes it goes `blank` value even though I've added `depends_on`. How can I fix this? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use the [`aws_eks_cluster` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/eks_cluster) to get this information like with the example?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR can you let me know how can i get thumbprint from `aws_eks_cluster` datasource?

Comment: You can combine it with the [`tls_certificate` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/tls/latest/docs/data-sources/tls_certificate) as shown in the example there.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR can you post that comment as answer? I'll mark as correct answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get the thumbprint of any certificate by using the [`tls_certificate` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/tls/latest/docs/data-sources/tls_certificate). The data source's resource docs helpfully show an example of how to get the thumbprint for the `aws_iam_openid_connect_provider` resource:

```
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "example" {
  name = "example"
}

data "tls_certificate" "example" {
  url = aws_eks_cluster.example.identity.0.oidc.0.issuer
}

resource "aws_iam_openid_connect_provider" "example" {
  client_id_list  = ["sts.amazonaws.com"]
  thumbprint_list = [data.tls_certificate.example.certificates.0.sha1_fingerprint]
  url             = aws_eks_cluster.example.identity.0.oidc.0.issuer
}
```